# BizTalk: Service Consumer Catalog

Tags: biztalk, soa, uddi

Is there a way in BizTalk, or any third party product, to know about service consumers. For Example, which channels/systems are using service X. 
I have seen maintaining an excel document for this mapping but is there any product for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOA Software](http://www.soa.com/solutions/microsoft/soa_governance_for_biztalk/) is one company that has some sort solutions for these kind of problems. It is however quite expensive.

Try and search for [SOA governance](http://www.google.se/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=soa%20governance) and you'll find plenty more options.